# App crashes in Thread 0 (Only on AdHoc)

Tags: ios, uitableview, crash, crash-reports, ad-hoc-distribution

My app was recently rejected for a crash when loading a tableview. I could only reproduce the crash when running an ad-hoc build. Here's the crash log:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x30ecbe7e __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b2286c2 objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x30ecf7b2 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 198
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30ece0aa ___forwarding___ + 702
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30e1cdc4 __forwarding_prep_0___ + 20
5   HSHacks                         0x0011a368 -[FRepo initWithRepoInfo:andPersistence:] (FRepo.m:51)
6   HSHacks                         0x00119b58 -[FRepoManager getLocalRepo:] (FRepoManager.m:85)
7   HSHacks                         0x0011a1f0 +[FRepoManager getRepo:] (FRepoManager.m:126)
8   HSHacks                         0x00132144 -[Firebase initWithUrl:] (Firebase.m:50)
9   HSHacks                         0x000d0d8c -[ChatViewController viewDidLoad] (ChatViewController.m:61)
10  UIKit                           0x33654956 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 514
11  UIKit                           0x33654714 -[UIViewController view] + 20
12  UIKit                           0x3377bd8a -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 350
13  UIKit                           0x3377bc1e -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 34
14  UIKit                           0x3377bb2a -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 254
15  UIKit                           0x33846840 -[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:] + 268
16  UIKit                           0x33684d9e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 86
17  UIKit                           0x33684d3a -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 34
18  UIKit                           0x338466f6 -[UITabBar _sendAction:withEvent:] + 366
19  UIKit                           0x33684d9e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 86
20  UIKit                           0x33684d3a -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 34
21  UIKit                           0x33684d0e -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 42
22  UIKit                           0x3367073e -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 370
23  UIKit                           0x33684d9e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 86
24  UIKit                           0x33684d3a -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 34
25  UIKit                           0x33684d0e -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 42
26  UIKit                           0x3367073e -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 370
27  UIKit                           0x33684756 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 590
28  UIKit                           0x3364819c _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 5524
29  CoreFoundation                  0x30e96f64 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 16
30  CoreFoundation                  0x30e948f2 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 282
31  CoreFoundation                  0x30e94c3e __CFRunLoopRun + 734
32  CoreFoundation                  0x30dff46c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
33  CoreFoundation                  0x30dff24e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
34  GraphicsServices                0x35b392e6 GSEventRunModal + 134
35  UIKit                           0x336b4840 UIApplicationMain + 1132
36  HSHacks                         0x000d7efa main (main.m:16)
37  libdyld.dylib                   0x3b721ab2 tlv_initializer + 2


Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b7d81fc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b83fa4e pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b789028 abort + 72
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3abd798a abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3abf06e2 default_terminate_handler() + 250
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b228936 _objc_terminate() + 190
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3abee1b0 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3abedd12 __cxa_rethrow + 98
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b22880a objc_exception_rethrow + 38
9   CoreFoundation                  0x30dff4e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 638
10  CoreFoundation                  0x30dff24e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
11  GraphicsServices                0x35b392e6 GSEventRunModal + 134
12  UIKit                           0x336b4840 UIApplicationMain + 1132
13  HSHacks                         0x000d7efa main (main.m:16)
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x3b721ab4 start + 0
```

Anybody have any idea what's going on?

I think it may have something to do with this code in viewDidLoad:

```
    [self.firebase observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
        // Add the chat message to the array.
        [self.chat addObject:snapshot.value];
        // Reload the table view so the new message will show up.
         [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

        [self.chatTableView reloadData];
        self.chatTextField.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
         [self.chatTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.chat.count-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];
    }];

}
```

Comment: You forget to include the complete error message about what selector couldn't be found.

Comment: And post the `initWithRepoInfo:andPeristence:` method of your `FRepo.m` file and point out which line is line 51.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm using Firebase chat API for this, so FRepo.m probably shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: Read the stack trace. That's exactly where the problem is. Line 51 of FRepo.m.

Comment: Hm. I'm new to reading stack traces - for the sake of learning, what tells you that?

Comment: And it's part of the Firebase.framework so I can't find the FRepo.m - but looking for it

Comment: The line that starts with 5.

Comment: Yup, you were right. The line appropriately had: [FRepo youForgotToSetMinusObjCInTheOtherLinkerFlagsInYourXCodeProject];

I just fixed that and it worked.

Comment: That's a clever way to deal with that.